# How do I "bake" the displacement of an procedural material (with the right orientation) to the mesh?

Tags: mesh, displacement, 3d-printing, procedural

I have a question for you guys!
Recently I was searching for a way to better present my digital sketches and bought the realistic clay shaders by jama jurabaev. https://gumroad.com/l/KqHnv
Here are some of my first render tests. I was thinking about actually 3D printing this piece, do you know how to bake the displacement of this procedural clay shader to the mesh?[image]

Comment: I guess you need to display the black & white picture, bake it, then use it in a Displace modifier so that it moves the mesh for real, it will need a mesh that is enough subdivided though

Comment: Thank you. You are right, but it is quite hard to bake it with the same displacement location. The material is procedural and the mesh does not have any UV's.

Comment: you need first to unwrap your object, Smart UV Project should be ok